# Send email using outlook smtp through Node js

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, starttls

I'm trying to send an email using Nodemailer package. I am getting different errors may be because of wrong configuration setting of TLS. My outlook SMTP uses STARTTLS but I don't know how to use it. I have configured it successfully for Gmail but getting an error when implementing with outlook. Please explain or give an example. I have been googling for 2 days but unable to get it. Thanks.

code snippet is as below:

```
const transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.office365.com',
    service:'office365',
    port: 587,
    secure: false,  //true for 465 port, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: 'kuxxxxxxxxxxxxin',
      pass: 'Mxxxxxxxx3'
    },      
    secureConnection: false,
    tls: {
        ciphers: 'SSLv3',
        rejectUnauthorized: true
    }
});
```

Comment: It is difficult to help you without the code you tried and minimal informations: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have edited the question..Plz see the code

Comment: Check out the documentation on [Nodemailer's TLS options](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/#tls-options). You may also want to read Microsoft's [How to set up a multifunction device or application to send email using Office 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-office-3?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fhow-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-office-365-69f58e99-c550-4274-ad18-c805d654b4c4).

Answer (score 1):

Office 365 no longer supports SSL v3 because of it security vulnerabilities. You must use at least TLS 1.2

Comment: when I check the outlook setting then I got encryption type STARTTLS. But I have no idea that how to transport with that encryption type.